# Upload web resource to Microsoft Dynamics CRM programmatically with Node.js

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

According to this [issue](https://github.com/mkloubert/vs-deploy/issues/2), I would like to **upload web resources** to a **Microsoft Dynamics CRM** via **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)** based API.

**Is there a way to do this with things like a common HTTP request?**

For example:

I want to update the resource `https://MyOrganization.crm.dynamics.com/WebResources/test/test.htm`.

Is it possible to do someting like that ([cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) example; *PUT* request):

`curl -T .\localTest.htm https://MyOrganization.crm.dynamics.com/WebResources/test/test.htm --user MyOrganization\mkloubert:password`

**Or is there another way to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

CRM stores web resources a bit differently. CRM does not store web resources in their native html/js/png format, rather, the files are encoded and converted to a base64 string and stored in the `content` attribute of a web resource.

Also to use RESTful http methods, you would have to use the [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx) endpoint and try to create a [Web Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx) with the encoded data as the content of the web resource.